# here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF_$$')

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is the Jenkins groovy code executing shell script:

```
    BUILD_FULL = sh (
                script: '''
                        cat > manifest.yml << EOF_$$
                        ---
                        applications:
                        - name: xyz-api
                          instances: 1
                          memory: 1G
                        EOF_$$
                        ''',
                returnStatus: true
                ) == 0
```

---

where below is the error:

```
line 9: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF_$$')
```

`manifest.yml` shows as:

```
                        ---
                        applications:
                        - name: xyz-api
                          instances: 1
                          memory: 1G
                        EOF_31892
```

instead of

```
                        ---
                        applications:
                        - name: xyz-api
                          instances: 1
                          memory: 1G
```

---

How to track end of file? using Jenkins groovy

Comment: In bash, $$ represents the process ID of the script, you should remove that from the EOF_$$ - Just use EOF

Comment: @AdamvonNieda Line should end with `EOF_<process_id>`

Comment: @AdamvonNieda If I remove `_$$`, I get this error: `line 9: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')` which make sense to me

Comment: You can't indent the closing delimiter.

Comment: @chepner Got it, removed spaces(indentation)

Comment: Yes; I don't know exactly how Jenkins processes the file, but as far as the actual *shell* that runs the script is concerned, you need `EOF_$$` to start at the beginning of the line. Write the other code/configuration/etc accordingly.